# Can you have multiple working directories with github actions?

Tags: go, github-actions

So I have a repo with multiple directories for multiple go projects. Is there a way to run github actions on multiple working directories so I don't have to have redundant yaml with github actions? To automate an error check with golang, I currently have:

```
  errcheck:
    name: Errcheck
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: check
      uses: grandcolline/golang-github-actions@v1.1.0
      working-directory: ./app1
      with:
        run: errcheck
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

But I'd like to have:

```
  errcheck:
    name: Errcheck
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: check
      uses: grandcolline/golang-github-actions@v1.1.0
      working-directory: [./app1, ./app2]
      with:
        run: errcheck
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: do these two directories have any inter dependency?

Comment: No they are totally separate applications

Answer (score 9):

In order to run something in more than one working directory, I believe you have two options:

**Option 1: Matrix**

Use GitHub Action's [jobs.<job_id>.strategy.matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix) option. This will create multiple jobs, each with its own matrix (directory) value.

Here is a sample workflow:

```
name: Test
on:
  push: { branches: master }

jobs:
  test:
    name: Matrix test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: { dir: ['some-dir', 'other-dir'] }

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Do something with the matrix value
      working-directory: ${{ matrix.dir }}
      run: pwd
```

Running this will create two jobs:

[image]

**Option 2: Custom Shell Script**

If the matrix option is not suitable for your needs, a simple shell script that loops through and tests all your nested applications (directories) might be appropriate. In this case, you ignore the `working-direcoty` directive in the workflow YAML, and let the script `cd` to each of them.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dirs=( some-dir other-dir )

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  pushd "$dir"
  pwd    # Do something more significant here
  popd
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this write-up! I'm trying to follow it for my example, but seem to be having some issues, what I'm trying to do is something similar to as follows:

Comment: ```
strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet-version: ['3.1.x', '3.5.x']
        dirs: ['example_dir1', 'example_dir2']
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
          working-directory: ${{ matrix.dirs }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: dotnet restore
      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
'''